# Pandas Columns with Date and Time - How to sort?

Tags: python, pandas

I have concatenated several `csv files` into `one dataframe` to make a `combined csv file`. But one of the `columns` has both `date` and `time` `(e.g 02:33:01 21-Jun-2018)` after being `converted to date_time` format. However when I call

```
new_dataframe = old_dataframe.sort_values(by = 'Time')
```

It sorts the dataframe by time , completely ignoring date.

```
Index                   Time   Depth(ft)  Pit Vol(bbl)  Trip Tank(bbl)
189147  00:00:00 03-May-2018   2283.3578      719.6753         54.2079
3875    00:00:00 07-May-2018   5294.7308     1338.7178         29.5781
233308  00:00:00 20-May-2018   8073.7988      630.7964         41.3574
161789  00:00:01 05-May-2018    122.2710      353.6866         58.9652
97665   00:00:01 01-May-2018  16178.8666      769.1328         66.0688
```

How do I get it to sort by dates and then times , so that `Aprils` days come first, and come in `chronological order`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to sort with your `date` first and then `time`, your `Time` column should be in the right way `Date followed by Time`. Currently, it's opposite.

You can do this:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.split(' ').str[::-1].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

Now sort your df by `Time` like this:

```
df.sort_values('Time')
```

Comment: That sorted it, did not see it was the wrong way round.